# PHP - get rows in MySQL database ordered by serialized dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization

I have ran into a predicament on this system I have been working on. In the table "class" there are multiple rows of classes. The column I am focusing on is "dates". On the admin dashboard, I need to be able to list the classes by the closest date to the farthest away. I tried using this but it does not work the way I want it to.

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM class ORDER BY dates ASC")
```

My problem is that the column "dates" is actually a serialized array of the start and end dates. Because of this I can't use `strtotime()` to make the above code work 100% correctly.

My overall question is, is there any way I can sort a query by a serialized date string?

I know opinions of different ways to do it will arise, but that's not what I'm shooting for. If it is possible or you have any idea, please post an answer.

Comment: Do you have an example entry of `dates`?

Comment: If you need to query based on data in a serialized array, then you probably shouldn't be storing it as a serialized array in the first place. Formalize the data into its own columns, or its own table structure. This is the whole point of an RDBMS.

Comment: @TobiasKun here is an example `a:2:{i:0;s:10:"02/21/2015";i:1;s:10:"02/23/2015";}`

Comment: @Sammitch although your opinion is probably correct, are you saying my question is impossible? It is still an issue that if someone had knowledge to fix it the way it stands, they would be more useful.

Comment: It is probably *possible*, but not in any way that is either *sane* or *efficient*. If you want to do it entirely within SQL it will require string matching/parsing and then casting to DATE. You're probably better off first reducing your result set as far as possible without the serialized data, then pulling it all into PHP and filtering it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql order by serialized data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234057/mysql-order-by-serialized-data)

> No, it is not possible. The only possible case when serialized data is acceptable is when you don't need to search or order by through that data. In all other cases - store your data as a separated fields.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm surprised I didn't see that post when searching.