# Woocommerce order by custom callback function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added a new sorting option to Woocommerce, which would sort by the lowest price. All my prices are stored in a custom attribute, along with some other serialized data. What I want is to have a callback function which would unserialize this data, check for the lowest price and sort by that price.

Every post I saw about custom ordering options, makes use of the `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` filter to add orderby arguments to WP_Query, but I haven't seen any way to sort the results of the returned query via a callback function.

Is there any way to achieve this? I was looking at `woocommerce_after_product_ordering` based on the name, but couldn't find much info about it. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function my_woocommerce_product_sorting($orderby) {
    $orderby['price_asc'] = "Sort by cheapest";
    $orderby['price_desc'] = "Sort by most expensive";

    return $orderby;
}
add_filter("woocommerce_catalog_orderby", "my_woocommerce_product_sorting", 20);
```

Comment: WooCommerce already sorts by prices, both ascending and descending. What does "All my prices are stored in a custom attribute" mean? Why aren't prices stored in the `_price` meta? As far as I know, there is no way to sort the results of a query by a callback function. The query sorts itself depending on the `order` and `orderby` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be best solution when you store custom price with separate new meta key like wooocommerce store product price in post meta name **_price** and value with numeric price.

[mysql order by serialized data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234057/mysql-order-by-serialized-data)

When you store separated then it will change wp query args like :

```
function my_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ){

    $order_by = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : $args['orderby'];

    if( $order_by == 'price_desc' || $order_by == 'price_asc' ){ // Check match to custom filter

      $args['orderby']  = "meta_value_num ID";
      $args['order']    = $order_by == 'price_desc' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
      $args['meta_key'] = '_my_custom_price'; // Put your price custom post meta price key name     

    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'my_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
```

Comment: This is not the solution I wished for, but it was the one I went for in the end, with no better alternatives.