# PHP loop sorting by numbers group

Tags: php

I have foreach and for loops, first one just get results from database and second one is for serialazed data.

```
<?php 

foreach($result as $row):

  $arr = unserialize($row['worked_days']);
  for($i = 1; $i <= count($arr['days']); $i++):
    if ($arr['days'][$i] > 0):

      echo $arr['days'][$i].'-'.$row['pmonth'];
      echo $row['title']; ?>
      echo $row['start_time'];

    endif;
  endfor;

endforeach; 

?>
```

My result now is:

```
Date    Title

1-11    Some title              
2-11    Some title                  
3-11    Some title              
1-11    My other title          
2-11    My other title
```

But i need, like this:

```
1-11    Some title
1-11    My other title
2-11    Some title
2-11    My other title
3-11    Some title
```

I need first print all 1 second all 2 and 3 and etc.. Because of serialized data i cant group or order with sql, so how i can do this inside loop?

Result from database var_dump:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
   array (size=12)
     'title' => string 'Some title' (length=12)
     'start_time' => string '13:00:00' (length=8)
     'worked_days' => string 'a:5:{s:4:"days";"0:'... (length=1971)
     'pmonth' => string '11' (length=2)

 1 => 
  array (size=12)
    'title' => string 'My other title' (length=12)
    'start_time' => string '13:00:00' (length=8)
    'worked_days' => string 'a:5:{s:4:"days";"0:'... (length=1971)
    'pmonth' => string '11' (length=2)
```

From serialazed data var_dump

```
array (size=6)
  'days' => 
        array (size=30)
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
          3 => string '3' (length=1)

array (size=6)
  'days' => 
        array (size=30)
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
          3 => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: Putting <?php ... ?> on each line makes it very difficult to read. Why not just open at the start and close at the end? Use indentation as well to show how your code is structured. It makes it easier to spot logic errors.

Comment: you sort the days array  before start loop

Comment: @Nick Oh.. sorry it was just copy/paste from my project template file, i just fixed this php tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql order by serialized data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234057/mysql-order-by-serialized-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has been tested in **PHP version 7.1**, it is 100% sure that it will not work in earlier versions of PHP (where Type Hint is not supported) you can easily make the code to support older versions by removing the TypeHints and using the old array() syntax.

In the following code I am using the **BinaryTree** Structure to sort the data by using the in-order traversal
I created an Object for your data **MyData** with a custom **compareTo()** function.

Firstly I insert your data (*created some dummy data for test purpose based on your var_dumps*) into the BinaryTree and then i use the function **getNodesOrdered** of my BinaryTree Class which returns an array of **MyData** objects that is sorted based on month and day

```
/**
 * Custom data structure that holds your data separated for each day
 * You can customize the name of the class and add/remove the parameters.
 */
class MyData
{

    private $title;
    private $startTime;
    private $day;
    private $month;

    public function __construct($title, $startTime, $day, $month)
    {
        $this->title     = $title;
        $this->startTime = $startTime;
        $this->day       = $day;
        $this->month     = $month;
    }

    public function setTitle($title = ""): MyData
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setStartTime($startTime = "00:00:00"): MyData
    {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartTime(): string
    {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    public function setDay($day = 1): MyData
    {
        $this->day = (int) $day;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDay(): int
    {
        return $this->day;
    }

    public function setMonth($month = 1): MyData
    {
        $this->month = (int) $month;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMonth(): int
    {
        return $this->month;
    }

    /**
     * Simple to string
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->day . "-" . $this->month . "\t" . $this->title . "\r\n";
    }

    /**
     * Compares current Instance with another one
     * @returns int, 1 if greater, 0 if equal, -1 if lesser
     */
    public function compareTo(MyData $data): int
    {
        //first checks the month
        if ($this->getMonth() > $data->getMonth())
        {
            return 1;
        } else if ($this->getMonth() < $data->getMonth())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        //then checks the day
        if ($this->getDay() > $data->getDay())
        {
            return 1;
        } else if ($this->getDay() < $data->getDay())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        //if day and month is equal that means that both instances are equal
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Class MyDataNode (BinaryTree nodes)

```
class MyDataNode
{

    private $data;
    private $left;
    private $right;

    public function __construct(MyData $data)
    {
        $this->left  = null;
        $this->right = null;
        $this->data  = $data;
    }

    public function setLeft(MyDataNode $node): MyDataNode
    {
        $this->left = $node;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setRight(MyDataNode $node): MyDataNode
    {
        $this->right = $node;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLeft(): ?MyDataNode
    {
        return $this->left;
    }

    public function getRight(): ?MyDataNode
    {
        return $this->right;
    }

    public function setData(MyData $data): MyDataNode
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getData(): MyData
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

}
```

MyDataBinaryTree (BinaryTree with MyDataNodes as Nodes)

```
class MyDataBinaryTree
{

    private $root;
    private $ordered;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->root = null;
    }

    public function isEmpty(): bool
    {
        return ($this->root == null);
    }

    //insert MyData instance to the binary Tree
    public function insert(MyData $data): void
    {
        if (is_null($this->root))
        {
            $this->root = new MyDataNode($data);
            return;
        }

        $current = $this->root;

        while (true)
        {
            //if the data we try to set is greater than the current item
            if ($data->compareTo($current->getData()) < 0)
            {
                if ($current->getLeft())
                {
                    // if the there is already an item on the left leaf set current as left and repeat the process
                    $current = $current->getLeft();
                } else
                {
                    // else set the left leaft as the current object
                    $current->setLeft(new MyDataNode($data));
                    return;
                }
            } else if ($data->compareTo($current->getData()) >= 0)
            {
                //if the data we try to set is equal or lesser than the current item
                if ($current->getRight())
                {
                    // if the there is already an item on the right leaf set current as right and repeat the process
                    $current = $current->getRight();
                } else
                {
                    //else set right leaf as the new data object
                    $current->setRight(new MyDataNode($data));
                    return;
                }
            } else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public function countNodes(MyDataNode $r = null): int
    {
        if (is_null($r))
        {
            return 0;
        } else
        {
            $length = 1;
            $length += $this->countNodes($r . getLeft());
            $length += $this->countNodes($r . getRight());
            return $length;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return array of MyData objects
     */
    public function getNodesOrdered(): array
    {
        $this->ordered = [];
        $this->_inOrder($this->root);
        return $this->ordered;
    }

    /**
     * set the data of the nodes with in-order traversal
     */
    private function _inOrder(MyDataNode $node): void
    {
        if ($node->getLeft())
        {
            $this->_inOrder($node->getLeft());
        }

        $this->ordered[] = $node->getData();

        if ($node->getRight())
        {
            $this->_inOrder($node->getRight());
        }
    }

}
```

Here are the data that I used to test the code.

```
/**
 * Create dummy data for test purpose
 */
$dummyData   = [];
$dummyData[] = [
    "title"       => "Some title",
    "start_time"  => "13:00:00",
    "worked_days" => serialize(["days" => [1, 2, 3]]),
    "pmonth"      => "11"
];
$dummyData[] = [
    "title"       => "My other title",
    "start_time"  => "13:00:00",
    "worked_days" => serialize(["days" => [1, 2]]),
    "pmonth"      => "11"
];

$dummyData[] = [
    "title"       => "Title 3",
    "start_time"  => "13:00:00",
    "worked_days" => serialize(["days" => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]),
    "pmonth"      => "12"
];
$dummyData[] = [
    "title"       => "Title 4",
    "start_time"  => "13:00:00",
    "worked_days" => serialize(["days" => [3, 4, 5, 6]]),
    "pmonth"      => "12"
];
```

The code that parses the data

```
// Initialise the binary tree
$btree = new MyDataBinaryTree();

/**
 * loop through data rows (same as yours database data)
 */
foreach ($dummyData as $row){
    $arr = unserialize($row['worked_days']);
    //loop through unserialised worked_days
    foreach ($arr['days'] as $day)
    {
        //insert into the BinaryTree new MyData instances
        $btree->insert(new MyData($row['title'], $row['start_time'], $day, $row['pmonth']));
    }
}

//sort the MyData instances sorted
$sortedItems = $btree->getNodesOrdered();

//print the sorted Data
foreach ($sortedItems as $item)
{
    echo $item; //calling the __toString();
}
```

You can check the code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cce23959991a05fef7d350a2195ab1dcca366cf2)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use the php function [sort](https://php.net/sort)

```
$arr = unserialize($row['worked_days']);
sort($arr['days']);
```

Comment: try to do 
$arr = unserialize($row['worked_days']);
$days = $arr['days'];
$sortedDays = sort($days);

Comment: It's no point from the $sortedDays variable, because this function returns boolean.