# How to use ORDER BY of a serialized value?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi is there a way I can prioritize the order by of an sql result?

Example I have a `$_POST['adventure_type']` request that has a value of `3`, `4` and in my table I have 5 data.
The field name is `adventure_type`.

**First Data** has a value of `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"6";}`

**Second Data** has a value of `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"3";}`

**Third Data** has a value of `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"4";}`

**Fourth Data** has a value of `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"6";}`

**Fifth Data** has a value of `a:2:{i:0;s:1:"3";i:1;s:2:"15";}`

And when I use the query below example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY adventure_type ASC
```

I can get a result of **Second Data**, **Third Data**, **Fifth Data**, **First Data**, **Fourth Data**  in an order by of an `adventure_type`.

Comment: It's not possible, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234057/mysql-order-by-serialized-data

Comment: Well it could be possible.. @RaminRezazadeh, the question is of this would make sense as PHP `serialize()` output is explained and documentated one could build a `unserialize()` in MySQL to parse that serialized string..  But also a option would to convert this into JSON as MySQL has native JSON functions, but parsing dynamic JSON keys in MySQL is trouble some and you have to write tricky MySQL code if you  don't have MySQL 8 where `JSON_TABLE()` exists

Comment: if you store to JSON format, you can use JSON_EXTRACT in select query and after that ordered by the extracted field.

Comment: for example: 
`SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(jsonColumn, '$.sampleData') AS sampleData 
FROM sampleTable ORDER BY sampleData ASC`

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh using dynamic JSON elements what the topicstarter would have then simply involves writting more tricky SQL then that..